Handling a customer that is contacting my subordinates on LinkedIn demanding a refund (already given)?
The company I work for sells a subscription based service. I recently found out that a customer who cancelled and was refunded every penny that they spent with us has been contacting employees on their LinkedIn's demanding money back that they already got.
In their communications with the company they've been told that the refund has been issued and yet they persist. The fact that they're contacting employees outside of work, however, is crossing a line.
I've tried to contact the owner of the company to see what our options are but haven't been able to get ahold of him. He's out of the country for the rest of the year.
In lieu of the owners feedback I'm thinking that maybe I should pursue getting a restraining order against the ex-customer or trying to file some sort of criminal charges for harassment? I could wait but, in the meantime, if said customer is going to continue their campaign of harassment I am concerned that some of my subordinates could take matters into their own hands.
Are there any better options I haven't considered?

If you have a Legal Department you should consider having them issue a "Cease and Desist" letter - https://www.gannons.co.uk/insights/cease-and-desist/

What country, and if applicable state or province is this happening in? Does this customer have a presence in your country?  Your rights and options can greatly change depending on the answers to these questions.

a lawyer letter is milder (and cheaper) than a restraining order. They have worked for me in the past. So has contacting someone and asking them to spare me the hassle of getting my lawyer involved.

The root cause of your difficulties here seems to be that the owner of your company has gone on holiday without leaving details of how he can be contacted in an emergency. Make sure you resolve that in January.

@PhilipKendall very important observation sir, otherwise a similar situation will come on the next emergency

Tell your employees to ignore any communication from this customer, via LinkedIn or elsewhere. When the owner of your company is back, refer this matter to them. This customer isn't "really" contacting employees outside of work. They're contacting them via LinkedIn because they are listed as employees of your company. Let your owner handle the matter.

Is this customer a private person, so acting on their own, or are they an employee of a company that is your customer?

What exactly does the customer want from your company now that he already got the refund ? Does he know that he already got the refund back into his bank account ? Did you company give him 100% or 75% of his money back ? What makes him unhappy still ?

LinkedIn has a way for a user to block anyone he does not communicate with. Similarly, all email softwares have a way to block unwanted emails from some senders. Smart phones can do the same thing.

How do you know that the (ex)customer has actually received their refund? You write that "the refund has been issued", which I read as "we've clicked some buttons on our end", but have you verified that this refund transaction has actually completed successfully (or is at least still "on-track")?

Are you sure this is the actual customer and not a 'social engineering' exercise by some third party?

You have a balancing act to perform.

This customer will never be "a referable client". So you have an urge to not be nice or to be confrontational. (thanks to @donald for callout on my phrasing)

You don't want your staff thinking it is OK to be rude, even if it is warranted. Other clients might see public interactions.


Give your staff a simple script that states to please contact support during business hours (or something similar) for help.
Let your staff know that this client has received a refund already and some of their team members might be confused. NO TRASH TALK - It isn't about them, it is about how you will be judged by your team. This is your real goal here - even if your are not the owner
Be friendly and firm about any communications. Stick to "on xx/xx/20xx we refunded $yyyy, how else can we help you?".
Document all interactions in case it ends up in court.

“So you don't want to be nice.” - You can still be polite to even the worse behaving customer. I would tell all staff to ignore any customer who reaches out to them privately on their personal social media.

I am not saying to not to be nice. I saying that the urge is to not be nice and to be polite for the reasons listed. Good catch on my wording.

I think the key is to ignore abusive customers. Give them 2 warnings or whatever you feel is appropriate, and then ignore them.  Of course, if you do that, you must be prepared to issue a refund and cut your losses, even if it breaks your refund policy. As for the reason you refund them, that is because if you don't refund their money, they will just issue a chargeback, which is more trouble than it's worth.

If you do go the "please contact support during business hours" route, this might be a good opportunity to establish a general "how to handle customers contacting you via personal channels" policy.

staff should probably ignore and block customers reaching out on social media

@WayneWerner consider if you were a prospect or another client and saw a client being ignored. Always own problems. Let the observers see who is being reasonable and who isn't and make their own conclusions.

@DogBoy37 if I was on LinkedIn and saw someone yelling at random employees and not the CEO, Media manager, I would assume the yeller doesn't understand how to contact companies. If they're @-ing the official channels and being ignored, that's different. If they're @-ing a CEO, that's far different than @-ing DogBoy37 about StackExchange.


In lieu of the owners feedback I'm thinking that maybe I should pursue getting a restraining order against the ex-customer or trying to file some sort of criminal charges for harassment?

Both of those options you mention sound a bit extreme to me, and probably also not something you have a strong case to work on (I am not a lawyer, nor do I know your location, but I highly doubt that what this person is doing is a criminal offense).
Perhaps a better way to handle this is:

Send an email, DM, phone call, whatever you can do to reach out to the owner to get their feedback. I suppose this owner is your direct manager. If not, contact your manager and inform them of the situation.

In the meantime, maybe you can inform your subordinates to either (1) ignore this persons messages on LinkedIn or (2) tell them to redirect this person to whatever your official channel of communication is.

Double and triple check that this person has indeed been refunded, or that they have been send the corresponding documents that evidence this. Perhaps they were left out of the loop and they still think they are owed something.



Redirecting unsolicited contacts regarding company business to the adequate company channels should be standard company policy.

(+1) The standard to issue a restraining order is typically lower than to convict someone of a crime, it doesn't imply one has been committed already.

Generally, I would implement a company policy, if possible, that every message of any client that is received through a private channel is forwarded to a company email address, and that someone in the company filters and handles all this communication.

Just advise the other employees that contacting an employee's LinkedIn account is not the way that customers get anything. If they are contacted for anything company related, they should either take no action whatsoever, or reply by sending them an official company contact number, possibly just the URL of the company's website. Under no circumstances should they for example try to get a refund for this person.

Well, one option is to state to the customer that a full refund has already been issued, and ask the customer what they see as the remaining problem.
I realise it may have just escaped mention in your question, but it is desirable to develop some kind of theory about what is motivating the customer, and what the facts look like to them.
If they are simply being obtuse about having received the money they are seeking already, and if there appears to be no further depth to their behaviour than opportunistic fraud, then it may be sufficient to simply ignore them if they approach again through unconventional channels, and if you are sure there is no grievance and all possibilities for the customer's confusion or complaint have been explored.
It was probably a mistake to have acknowledged contact in the unconventional fashion at all, assuming you have.
I once dealt with the investigation of a very similar case many years ago in different employment, and I asked the customer to make a simple check on whether they had received a specific sum of money on a specific date, and when the customer refused to countenance making such a check and stating what the facts looked like at their end, which was a final gambit to see whether there was some kind of record-keeping problem at our end, I concluded the customer's real agenda was a petty attempt at fraud.
Finally, if the company owner is missing, then obviously there must be someone left in charge with the power to make urgent executive decisions, but if the owner is gone only for several weeks and you are not regarded as an important executive decision-maker able to make these decisions alone, then I would suggest it is self-evidently premature to be considering seeking restraining orders, and perhaps a sign of poor judgment.

If the fact of the refund is in dispute put the ex-customer in contact with your payment processor, that is assist them in opening a support ticket.
If the amount of the refund is in dispute tell them they'll that you believe the amount is correct and there will not be any more.
You can also say that you're trying to decide if this is libel or wire fraud.
What your emploees do in their personal time with their personal email accounts should not matter.  You can ask them to keep their responses if any entertaining.  He has already made it unprofessional by contacting their personal email.
